# How to restrict/provide access to particular entities of some ENTITY_TYPE to users which has email listed as field value?

Tags: 8, entities

I have a entity type Products with multiple entities in it. I want to give View, Edit, Delete Access of each entity to users only whose Emails are listed under field_user_email.
I want to restrict access to rest of the users, whose Email-id is not listed under field_user_email field.

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic question, so my answer will be generic too.

First, inserting email addresses of users to grant permissions is not a standard Drupal way, you have to have an entity reference pointing to the users.

If you are using Drupal 7 you can use [flexi access](https://www.drupal.org/project/flexiaccess)

For Drupal 8 you can find a previously answered question [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/250128/how-to-restrict-access-to-some-nodes-based-on-roles-or-users)