# Display content assigned to a group

Tags: 8, multi-sites

I am relatively new to Drupal, so I apologize in advanced if my question is confusing.

I am building a school website that will have a parent district site and then school websites within the district. I want to have give the teachers permission to only edit their own respective sites as well.

I feel like I could do this easier with D7 but I want to be future proof so I am attempting this with D8.

Are there any methods I could try to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all you'd need to do, is to use the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module.

Refer to my answer to "[How to configure access to courses for teachers and students?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/150808/39516)" for a sample configuration.

## Resources

- [Community documentation for the Group module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2666972).
- Video tutorial "[How to use the Group module in Drupal 8 to manage editorial access control to different areas of a web site](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=GkiCLJk5n0s)".